# SVG nested <svg> vs group

Tags: svg

I know that there are two ways in SVG to group shapes together and position them as a collection: nesting `<svg>` tag and `<g>` grouping. However, I don't see much difference between them. For example, the following two pieces of code produce exactly the same result:

Using group [(jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/8q4on01m/5/):
https://jsfiddle.net/8q4on01m/5/

```
<svg width="5000" height="5000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g transform="translate(200 200)">
    <rect x="0" y="0" height="100" width="100" style="fill: yellow"></rect>

    <rect x="0" y="0" height="100" width="100" style="fill: green" transform="rotate(45) translate(200 100)"></rect>

    <rect x="0" y="0" height="100" width="100" style="fill: red" transform="translate(200 100)"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Using `<svg>` [(jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/54Lk7e02/5/):

```
<svg width="5000" height="5000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <svg x="200" y="200">
    <rect x="0" y="0" height="100" width="100" style="fill: yellow"></rect>

    <rect x="0" y="0" height="100" width="100" style="fill: green" transform="rotate(45) translate(200 100)"></rect>

    <rect x="0" y="0" height="100" width="100" style="fill: red" transform="translate(200 100)"></rect>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Which one is preferred/recommended? What are the pros and cons, important features of each? I am especially interested in handling bubbling click events issues.

Comment: <svg> requires more memory than <g> per element created. If you need its functionality, use it, if you don't don't.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your two examples, there is no real difference between `<svg>` and `<g>`.

However `<svg>` can do many things that `<g>` cannot. Groups are just a passive grouping of elements, and all they can really do is specify some properties that their children all inherit.

Inner `<svg>` elements establish a new viewport.  So you can do everything that the outermost `<svg>` can (actually more).

For example, by adding `width`, `height` and `viewBox` attributes to the inner SVG, you can scale its contents.

```html
<svg width="5000" height="5000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <svg x="200" y="200" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
    <rect x="0" y="0" height="100" width="100" style="fill: yellow"></rect>

    <rect x="0" y="0" height="100" width="100" style="fill: green" transform="rotate(45) translate(200 100)"></rect>

    <rect x="0" y="0" height="100" width="100" style="fill: red" transform="translate(200 100)"></rect>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

This is not a very exiting example. Instead, have a [look at this one](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/coords/PreserveAspectRatio.svg) from the SVG specification.

Comment: It might be worth noting that child SVGs embedded inside a parent SVG are fine as inline SVG but break when placed in HTML as an <IMG href> (presumably for security reasons). Using a group (G) will be fine in that scenario.

Comment: Is there any performance penalty when using nested `<svg>` instead of `<g>`?

Comment: @DenisItskovich No. There shouldn't be any significant performance penalty.

Comment: @Alex do you have a source for that? I can't seem to find more info.