# Angular: Using ComponentFactoryResolver for dynamic instantiation of the components, rendering inside SVG

Tags: html, angular, svg

I have a component, which renders DOM, which is expected to be inside `svg` tag:

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'g[hello]',
  template: `<svg:text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle">Hello, {{name}}</svg:text>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

When I instantiate it statically, everything works fine (the text is visible on the page):

```html
<svg>
  <svg:g hello name="Static component"></svg:g>
</svg>
```

The following DOM is generated:

```html
<svg _ngcontent-iej-c129="">
  <g _ngcontent-iej-c129="" hello="" name="Static component" _nghost-iej-c130="" ng-reflect-name="Static component">
    <text _ngcontent-iej-c130="" text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="50%">
      Hello, Static component
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The problem starts when I try to instantiate the component dynamically, using ComponentFactoryResolver:

```html
<svg>
  <ng-container #container></ng-container>
</svg>
```

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef, static: true}) container: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Instantiating HelloComponent dynamically
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(HelloComponent)
    const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);
    componentRef.instance.name = 'Dynamic component'
  }
}
```

The produced DOM seems looking OK, but for some reason, the text is not visible on the page:

```html
<svg _ngcontent-iej-c129="">
  <!---->
  <g hello="" _nghost-iej-c130="">
    <text _ngcontent-iej-c130="" text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="50%">
      Hello, Dynamic component
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Please see [Reproduction at stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hna5vn)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume there are two questions here:

1. How to make it work?
2. Why is that happening?

The answer to the first question is using `svg` instead of `g` for grouping elements.
In your concrete example it would mean changing the selector:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'svg[hello]',
  template: `<svg:text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle">Hello, {{name}}</svg:text>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
```

And `app.component.html`:

```html
<svg>
  <svg hello name="Static component"></svg>
</svg>
```

- [Working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfarbm)
- [Nested `svg` vs group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959079/svg-nested-svg-vs-group)

Now let's get to the second question. Why is this happening?
Your selector doesn't contain `svg` namespace. In order to render it correctly the selector should be `svg:g[hello]`.
But that is impossible due to an old issue that's been there since Angular 5.
More details [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20337) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10404).

As mentioned in [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20337#issuecomment-507111243) comment the main issue here is that Angular selector cannot contain namespace for creating element.
Selector `svg:g[hello]` will be parsed to `g[hello]`, as a result Angular will use `document.createElement` instead of `document.createElementNS` to create new element.

Why using `svg[hello]` works?
Because if we use selector `svg[hello]` then it is parsed to `<svg child>` and for this tag Angular is [providing namespace implicitly](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/018477e2c4a31de69554c377ed25ba291636050a/packages/compiler/src/ml_parser/html_tags.ts#L85):

```js
'svg': new HtmlTagDefinition({implicitNamespacePrefix: 'svg'}),
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be related to the old Angular issue: [#10404](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10404), and also to the issue, mentioned by Vitalii: [#20337](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20337)

In [#10404](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10404), [DingWeizhe](https://github.com/DingWeizhe) suggests the following work around:

**Instead of this code:**

```js
    const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);
```

**To use this:**

```js
    const groupElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
    const componentRef = componentFactory.create(injector, [], groupElement);
    this.container.insert(componentRef.hostView)
```

This change solves the problem without replacing `<g>` with `<svg>`. An accepted answer, of course, also solves the problem, but I have some concern about performance penalty, which could cause such replacement.

Working stackblitz is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-41rgnb)

Comment: I left a note in github issue.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that it is related to the open issue, see

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20337

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this issue. I've also recently found another one, which also seems to be related: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10404